# Prevent breaking the line when checking the checkbox using asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

How can I prevent breaking the line after checking the checkbox (using ASP.net) ?
[I have to hide the text before checking the checkbox]

```
<tr>
<td class="auto-style48" style="vertical-align:top">
 Click to forward calls to phone:</td>
<td class="auto-style26">

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle_visibility(CheckBoxForward2Phone) {
    var e = document.getElementById(CheckBoxForward2Phone);
    if (e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('CheckBoxForward2Phone');">
<asp:CheckBox ID="tbForward2Phone" runat="server" /></a>&nbsp;
<div id="CheckBoxForward2Phone" style="display: none;">
Please forward incoming calls to my number/s, to my regular phone number at:<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="Forward2PhoneBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
</div>
  </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Try `visibility:hidden/visible` instead of `display`? It hides the content, but not the space the content takes.

Comment: @Teemu - I tried..It doesnt help :(

Comment: Please explain how ASP and Visual Studio are relevant to the question. If they are not, present a sample of the code as served to a browser and remove the misleading tagging. In addition, describe the intended functionality and rendering. Is the user really expected to check a checkbox that appears alone, with no label?

Comment: You should also provide a *complete* (though preferably minimal) testable case that actually reproduces the issue and state what should happen instead of normal behavior such as line breaking when content does not fit into available width.